# What's pthread in Boost?

Tags: boost, pthreads, boost-thread

I found there are also a pthread in Boost library, is it the same thing as the posix pthread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

boost threads(and other stuff like mutexes/locks/condition variables) are implemented on top of pthreads where that's available - which is most *nixes.